# How to use Material UI Select with React Hook Form if we need to select Multiple values

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to select multiple languages

```
const languages= [{ label: 'English', value: 'English' },{ label: 'French', value: 'French' },{ label: 'Arabic', value: 'Arabic' },{ label: 'Spanish', value: 'Spanish' }];
<Select 
multiple 
onChange={handleChange}
{...register('language')}>
 {languages?.map((ele, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={index} value={ele.value}> {ele.label}</MenuItem>
 ))}
</Select>
```

handle change function

```
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {    
    onChange && onChange(name, event.target.value);
  };
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#multiple-select

Answer (score 0):

you need to define some state

```
const [selectedLang, setSelectedLang] = useState([])
```

Inside your handle change you need to set the new values to the state

```
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {    
   setSelectedLang[event.target.value]
  };
```

they have a good example in the docs
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/